# Cannot load phpmyadmin with apache2

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin, debian-stretch

Running Debian Stretch 9.5 with apache2. After upgrading from Debian 8, I can no longer access phpmyadmin from `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`. I get a `page not found` error. Everything looks good on the apache config side:

- apache2.conf contains `IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` contains `phpmyadmin.conf` which symlinks to config in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`
- I purposefully introduced syntax error into phpmyadmin config file and reloaded apache and it choked as expected. So apache is definitely loading the config file.
- Alias in config file is set to `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` which is where the phpmyadmin files are installed.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the `phpmyadmin` package but that didn't help. I followed the instructions in `/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/README.debian.gz` which said to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin` but that didn't help either.

I think I'm overlooking something basic in my apache config but I'm not sure what. Thanks.

Comment: What error message do you get from Apache when you try to access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`?

Comment: Just a blank page with "Page Not Found" at the top. There's no HTML in the source code. Just those words.

Comment: I should add that I followed the instructions in the /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/README.debian.gz which said to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`. Didn't help.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. This server is set up for virtualhosts so I had to wrap the <Directory> directive in the phpmyadmin config with <VirtualHosts :80>. I'm now getting a proper html document returned (though it has a phpmyadmin error in it).

Comment: Can you write that up in an answer and mark it as such?

Answer (score 0):

My box was running with apache set to use Virtual hosts. I solved the problem by wrapping all the  apache directives with a single  directive in the `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` file like so:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
...
</Directory>
<Directory ...>
...
</Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>`